# How to get Infinite Data-Structures?

Tags: python, c++, data-structures

There are some algorithms which need "infinite Data-Structures" like an infinite two-dimensional grid of cells. How is such a problem tackeld? Are they maybe using "pseudo-infinite" structures where just a large amount of data is used? Or is there somehow a "resize" implemented, when capacity is not enough?

I am using a Cellular-Automata Algorithm, which is beeing computed on a 2000 x 2000 grid, but i would like to have the grid infinitely.

Comment: 1) resize, e.g. `vector` 2) store only what's used, e.g. `map`. 3) recursive data structure (pointer back to a previous element)

Comment: I've just edited my question, a map seems to be right decision, i will try to test it. In my case the key would be cartesian coordinates X / Y. I can somehow convert it to a id (x + y * length) or isn't it a good idea?

Comment: if it's really infinite, length should be infinite too ;) so, no... use a `pair`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Delaying the calculation (or creation) of each item in an infinite data structure until it is needed eliminates the problem of having to create an infinite data set.